# How can I achieve color transition on scrolling with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to achieve an effect on the navigation header just like this http://livearealabs.com/

How can it be done?

this is something of what i did jsfiddle.net/abismo/D6H33

Comment: With jQuery, divide different background colours to different section. If background colour is white, then change text colour to white.

Comment: some more details please which effect and what have you tried?

Comment: @vimes1984 I would say if you do not know how to do this, what can you try?

Comment: @mplugjan fair enough!

Comment: i like to have a nice transition of my navbar between sections.
this is something of what i did http://jsfiddle.net/abismo/D6H33

Comment: @4bism0 take a look below that method is how they achieve it with that site you posted

Answer (score 0):

Ok here goes after picking apart at that page quite a bit, there is actually 4 desperate menus and they are using translateY css property and playing with the z-index's to give the appearance of the menu actually changing color, you are going to have to read up on [translateY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)
and the scroll window scroll functions, I've put togehter a very basic version that requires a lot of work but you will hopefully get the gist:

```
var getheightblue = $('#divone').height();
var scroll = $(window).scroll();
var reduce = 0;
var increase = 100;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function () {
 var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       // downscroll code
        reduce = reduce -= 5;
        increase = increase -= 5;
        $('.wrap.dark.transparent').css('-webkit-transform', 'translateY(' + reduce + '%)');
        $('.wrap.light').css('-webkit-transform', 'translateY(' + increase + '%)');
   } else {
      // upscroll code
        reduce = reduce += 5
        increase = increase += 5
        $('.wrap.dark.transparent').css('-webkit-transform', 'translateY(' + reduce + '%)');
        $('.wrap.light').css('-webkit-transform', 'translateY(' + increase + '%)');
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;

});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vimes1984/MPVBn/99/)
good luck!